# T-SQL resume processing after expected "A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We run a nightly data sync procedure against an azure database. In order to ensure that this does not max out the DTU settings we would like to set the Service Objective to S12 for this procedure.

So we run the command:

```
ALTER DATABASE [ourdatabasehere] 
    MODIFY(EDITION='Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE='S12')
```

We then need to wait until this service objective is in place

```
WHILE (SELECT [DSO].[service_objective] 
       FROM sys.database_service_objectives [DSO]) = N'S12'
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
```

So that the rest of the code continues under the new Service objective.

The problem is that the connection drops when the Service objective takes effect. And this results in the query throwing an error

> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Putting the check in a `TRY / CATCH` doesn't appear to be helping. The query still terminates and the connection is dropped. Is there a way to catch this during execution of the query and reconnecting before proceeding?

Comment: if you put this as 3 steps in your sql agent job, you should be able to proceed, just make sure it continues on both failure and success. When second step fails due to kill connection, it will move on to step #3 where you can check if the objective actually completed and then run your sync. If you're running this from management studio, i don't think you can recover from a killed connection, but a real program can. Btw, nice user name!

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks!

Would you add your comment as an Answer please? Your suggestion is perfect and it does the job!

Comment: Great to hear, re-posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put this as 3 steps in your sql agent job, you should be able to proceed, just make sure it continues on both failure and success.

When second step fails due to killed connection, it will move on to step #3 where you can check if the objective actually completed and then run your sync.

If you're running this from management studio, i don't think you can recover from a killed connection, but a real program can.